# How do I change the size of a UIControl when highlighted?

Tags: ios, uicontrol

I have a `UIControl` subclass that changes appearance and size when touched, a bit like the button of an iOS keyboard turns into the typewriter hand when touched:

[image: keyboard sample]

I’m not sure how to write it. The idea is to draw a different shape when the default button shape is highlighted:

```
                    +---+
                    |   |
+---+               |   |
|   |  -> touch ->  |   | 
+---+               +---+
```

But since the default button is smaller than the highlighted shape, the bigger shape gets clipped. I have considered these options:

- Drawing outside the default frame. Does not seem to be possible.
- Changing the size of the control when highlighted. Feels quite hacky and error-prone.
- Enlarging the control to accomodate the larger shape. Feels “wrong”, I’d like to be able to work with the control in its smaller, default shape.

Is there a best practice for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few approaches:

1. You can draw outside the frame, you just have to make sure that `myView.clipsToBounds` is `False`. This would allow you to draw outside the bounds of the view inside another view and draw whatever extra content you would like.
2. That is probably the cleanest solution, but is also a bit "hacky" in my opinion. The other approach would be dirty (as you said) and to reset the frame size.
3. The last approach would be to create another view (the key pressed down) and throw it on top of the original (unpressed key) view.

All in all, it really comes down to what you're drawing / showing inside your view.

Comment: I think that `clipsToBounds` only applies to subviews, not to drawing done inside `drawRect:`. But I’m currently experimenting with it, using subviews to do the drawing.

Comment: @zoul try it, if my memory serves me correctly, then clipsToBound does apply to Core Graphics as well as subviews.

Comment: @zoul I should probably clarify by saying that you cannot just override `drawRect:` and draw whatever you would like, clipsToBound is for subviews, but if you set that to `NO`, and put another subview inside the original view, and draw in that view, it should work fine.

Comment: Looks like `clipsToBounds` and doing the drawing in subviews is the way to go. Thanks!